# Use pivot point or 3d cursor as center when scaling down verts in edit mode in 2.8 instead of selected volume center

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms, scale

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_YujWJSr6w, at 1:08 seconds in the video, he scales down some selected verts and they scale down in the direction of the pivot point +  3d cursor. I am trying to do the same thing but not getting the same result.

Before scaling down 
[image: object before scaling down]

After scaling down
[image: object after scaling down]
When I scale down the verts scale down together in the center of themselves (center of  selected volume?) and not towards the 3d cursor and or pivot point as desired.
I would really like them to stay at the 3d cursor as I plan on applying a mirror modifier.

In the video the person is using Blender 2.7 but I am using 2.8. I am assuming I have some setting incorrect somewhere, but have not been able to find it.

I moved the pivot point and 3d cursor to where I believe is the correct place.
I have tried changing the Transform Orientations option to Global, Local, and Cursor. I get the same result each time.

Any idea for other things I can try or something I might be missing?

link to .blend file [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your *pivot point* to *3D cursor*.
It's currently se to *median*.

Just click the *pivot point menu*, and select 3D cursor.

[image]

**Short explanation:**
When you're in *Object mode*, having your *pivot point* set to an object's *median* is very useful.

But in *Edit mode*, vertices don't care where the object's median point is.
They calculate their own median.
That's why there's the 3D cursor - to set your pivot point easily.